# How to estimate gas Price using Ethers.js prior to sending the transaction?

Tags: javascript, ethers.js

[image]I am trying to estimate gas using ethers. I have tried using `await this.signer.getGasPrice()` but this doesn't take into account my contract's function and my address.I saw that on ethers's documentation they have a function

```
await provider.estimateGas({ // Wrapped ETH address

to: "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2", // `function deposit() payable`

data: "0xd0e30db0", // 1 ether

value: parseEther("1.0") });
```

but this takes transaction data as an input?

How am I supposed to get tranaction data prior to submitting a transaction?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i get it right but if you want to estimateGas you send

1. contract address
2. methodId of required function
3. any amount to test
   and data is "0x" + first 4 bytes of keccak hash of the ASCII form of the signature, it is included in Abi of contract.
   i usually find it with etherscan in InputData part of transaction details for desired function

Answer (score 0):

This is the bear necessity of what you need to do:

```js
import { ethers } from "ethers";
// this is your compiled contract json
import Contract from "Contract.json";

const rpcEndpoint = "your endpoint with api if applicable";
const senderPrivateKey = "senders private key";
cosnt deployedConctractAddress = "your contract's deployed address";
const contractInterface = Contract.abi;

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(rpcEndpoint);
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(senderPrivateKey, provider)


const contractInstance = new ethers.Contract(deployedConctractAddress, contractInterface, signer);

// this is how you get your transaction object
const txObject = await contractInstance.yourMethod("arg1", "arg2 and so on");

const gasLimit = await provider.estimateGas(txObject.data);
const gasPrice = await provider.getGasPrice();

// at this point you can also chose to use a gas station to get current prices etc, adjust your final gas values and prices // 

// and finally call your 
const txResponse = contractInstance.contractInstance.yourMethod("arg1", "arg2 and so on", {gasPrice, gasLimit});

// and process results:
console.log("Transaction hash:", txResponse.hash);

await txResponse.wait(2)
```